# Ruby and Threads - Why isn't my script finishing?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a script that provisions nodes for a cluster remotely using Thread so I can do all of them at once.

Is there a better way I can do this so I get a return code, a clean exit, and a script that does not seem to run for an inordinate amount of time?

```
@threads = []

def process_node(apps_to_close, node)
  @threads << Thread.new do
    puts "now processing node #{node}\n"
    ...
  end
end

nodes.each do |node|
  process_node(apps_to_close, node)
end

@threads.each {|thr| thr.join}
```

Comment: I tried your code without the app-specific logic (e.g. just printing a sequence of numbers from the thread). It worked fine. Can you give more info on the problem? What is the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Think it is because I'm connecting to remote machines. I think it's just a matter of time before I start using a more appropriate tool like Ansible and consider important things like... maybe the machine should be pinged before I even try to interact with it. That's a prerequisite to provisioning the node. The more I learn about Ansible the more I hear it is better for this type of thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a limit to the amount of time you allow threads to run via [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html#method-i-join), which returns `nil` if the thread is still running when the timeout is reached. So you could rewrite this as:

```
...

results = @threads.collect { |thr| thr.join(1) } # wait 1 second for thread
@threads.each { |t| Thread.kill(t) }
results.any?(&:nil?) ? exit(1) : exit(0)
```

Comment: I want the threads to run until they are done... I will pick this answer because I think the answer is to set a reasonable timeout or to check prereqs (e.g. is the machine I'm provisioning reachable).